# How to set random cookie value using rand function in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

How to set random cookie value using rand function in PHP

I don't want to change the value while page refreshed when it once assigned.. until cookie destroy

My code is as follows

```
<?php 
    global $random; 
    $random= rand(0, 9999999); 
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$random])) {
        setcookie('user_cookie',$random, time() + (1), "/"); echo $_COOKIE[$random];
    }
    else {
        echo "Cookie '" . $_COOKIE[$random] . "' is set!<br>"; 
    }
    exit(); 
?>
```

Comment: use isset function of php

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['lg'])) {
    setcookie('lg', rand(1,10000), time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
echo $_COOKIE['lg'];
```

You can check if it is not set then set it.

Comment: my code is.. <?php global $random; $random= rand(0, 9999999); if(!isset($_COOKIE[$random])) { setcookie('user_cookie',$random, time() + (1), "/"); echo $_COOKIE[$random]; e } else { echo "Cookie '" . $_COOKIE[$random] . "' is set!<br>"; } exit(); ?>

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
define('COOKIE_KEY', 'COOKIE_KEY');
if (!array_key_exists(COOKIE_KEY, $_COOKIE)) {
    setcookie(COOKIE_KEY, mt_rand(1, 10), time()+3600);    
}
```

Comment: my code is.. <?php
global $random;
$random= rand(0, 9999999);
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$random]))
{
setcookie('user_cookie',$random, time() + (1), "/");

     echo $_COOKIE[$random];
     e

} else {
     echo "Cookie '" . $_COOKIE[$random] . "' is set!<br>";
     
}
exit();
?>

Answer (score 0):

Your set cookie code is incorrect and the cookie time is only 1 second

change your code as follows...

```
<?php 
//cookie_start();
global $random; 
$random= rand(0, 9999999); 
if(!isset($_COOKIE['user_cookie'])) {
    setcookie('user_cookie',$random, time() + (86400), "/");//86400 = 1 day
}
else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $_COOKIE['user_cookie'] . "' is set!<br>"; 
}
exit();  
?>
```